# Generating this error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I keep getting this error when I am trying to read the file. How do I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


MY_FILE = 'prokaryotes.csv'

df = pd.read_csv("prokaryotes.csv", parse_dates=[0], header=None, 
names=['datetime', 'consumption'])

df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df['datetime']]
df['time'] = [x.time() for x in df['datetime']]



TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Whats the exact error with trace?

Comment: It looks like `read_csv()` is returning None.  Are you sure the filename is correct?

Comment: @JohnGordon prertty sure it shouldn't be returning `None`. There is likely something else going on here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace the last 2 lines of your code by this:

```
df['date'] = df.datetime.apply(lambda s : s[:10])
df['time'] = df.datetime.apply(lambda s : s[-9:])
print(df)
```